# What is shared in a JVM

Tags: java, jvm

What do two different Java programs, running in one same Java Virtual Machine, share together?

Something comes to my mind, regarding singleton classes: They can only be instantiated once per JVM. This means that if two different Java programs use one same class, they are both accessing the same instance of that Singleton class?

What other things are shared?

Comment: They are operating within the same memory space as the JVM process, so, everything...

Comment: Is there any way to have two JVM's running in one same machine?

Comment: Yes.  Just run `java.exe` again. (sorry that should "run java command", but you get the idea)

Comment: So each new Java processes starts in a new JVM.

Comment: Yes.  May be you should try it and see.  Create a singleton, have a Java class access that singleton and print the `hashcode` from it.  Run the java command twice and see what the output is...

Comment: I will do so, thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: Correction: singleton classes can only be instantiated once per *classloader.*

Answer (score 1):

If you run the *java* command multiple times, you get multiple instances of the JVM.  In theory these are entirely separate with nothing shared, but some implementations of the JVM (now or in the past) might attempt to share some portions of the data.

I haven't looked at it recently, but about 10 years back there was a version of the Sun JVM that would attempt to "share" .class file images between JVM instances.  (This was supposedly useful on servers where there might be dozens of JVMs running at once and they might come and go fairly rapidly.)

I'm not recalling any other data shared, but there may have been more, or other data may have been added since.  (Though there really isn't much else that can be shared between JVMs.)

But again, in theory this should all be "transparent" and not affect the operation of an individual JVM instance.

There was also a provision for "warm started" JVMs that were partially loaded prior to the final command.  This did require some configuration on the part of the system admin, but was otherwise transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Two or more programs running in the same JVM shares everything. Regarding singleton, when written properly there will be one single instance of the class, which can be accessed by all the other objects.

Comment: that's not correct. the same class loaded by two independent class loaders will exist twice and you will have two singletons. the classes will be the same by name and signatures but be incompatible due to having separate `Class` instances.

Comment: That's true. Loading from different class loaders can yield multiple singleton objects.